# reorder date columns in r

Tags: r, date, multiple-columns

Hi I have the following data.frame

```
    variable   name    new_skill    01/05/2015   01/08/2014   02/01/2015   02/05/2014

    task1      H&I     A             3.76           4.0         3.5        4.5
    task2      H&I    Broadband      3.12           3.30        4.5        5.5
```

There is 2 years worth of weekly dates in the columns above...

How to reorder them?

I tried something like `data.frame[,order()]`

this didn't work.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
df[, order(as.Date(colnames(df), format = "%d/%m/%Y"))]
```

This would sort the date columns according to the date and rest all columns would append to the end according to their occurrence in the original data frame.